# Problem with Handler(getMainLooper()).removeCallbacks in Kotlin, Android St

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, runnable

I’m fairly new to Kotlin and am working with Handlers and Runnables.  I’ve written a very simple program with Start and Stop buttons as well as a TextView.  When the Start button is pressed, this starts incrementing an Int variable i which is written to the TextView.  This just keeps going and the aim is for the Stop button to stop the process. Using
handler = Handler()
it all works fine.  However, I realise this is depreciated and so I’ve tried it with
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
but the Stop button doesn’t work.
I’m sure there’s a simple solution, but I can’t figure it out.  Any help greatly appreciated.
Here are the buttons and textview in the activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Number: "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Start"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Stop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_start" />
```

Here is the code in MainActivity.kt that works

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
private lateinit var handler: Handler

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var btnStart = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_start)
    var btnStop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_stop)
    var tvNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_number)

    var i: Int

    handler = Handler()

    btnStart.setOnClickListener() {
        i = 0
        runnable = Runnable {
            i += 1
            tvNumber.text = "Number: $i"
            handler.postDelayed(
                runnable,
                500
            )
        }
        handler.postDelayed(
            runnable,
            1
        )
    }

    btnStop.setOnClickListener() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code (just the setOnClickListener functions - the rest is the same) using Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) where the Stop button doesn't work:

```
    btnStart.setOnClickListener() {
        i = 0
        runnable = Runnable {
            i += 1
            tvNumber.text = "Number: $i"
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
                runnable,
                500
            )
        }
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            runnable,
            1
        )
    }

    btnStop.setOnClickListener() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use 'handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)' to remove callbacks, and everywhere use handler reference don't create a new one

Comment: Thanks for this.  As I've mentioned below, does this mean that I should stick with the working code, even though it is depreciated?

Comment: Realise from the comment below how to fix it - not creating a new one as you say.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your not-working code is working on new `Handler` every time. Passing same looper in constructor doesn't mean that this object is also the same. So you are calling `removeCallbacks` on freshly created `Handler`, which doesn't have any callbacks posted, thus not working (not removing from previously created `Handler` with posted `runnable`)

btw. afaik creating `Handler` without a single argument also creates `Handler` with main `Looper` under the hood. but in first case you are referencing to one created `handler` object, so you can add callbacks or remove already posted

Comment: Thanks for this.  Does this mean then that the not-working code is not really going to work and I should stick with the working code, even though it is depreciated.

Comment: yes, first snippet is proper, but if you want to avoid deprecation warning just use `handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` instead fo deprecated `Handler()` (no-argument constructor). still keep reference to created `handler` object, post to it and romve from it callbacks

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for that.  Works perfectly and I now have a much better understanding of what is going on.